# Same DataFrame to be used by more functions in parallel/multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing

I'm opening a .csv with pd.read_csv and convert it into DataFrame. The DataFrame needs to some changes to be scaled accordingly. The scaling takes a few minutes, so it should be scaled only once.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(...))
for index, row in data.iterrow():
    data['specific_column'][index] = data['specific_column'][index] * (different scaling factors)
    etc.
```

Then there are several functions that do different things with this scaled df and I would like the functions to run simultaneously to save some time.

```
def function1(input_data, arg1 ....)
    do something

def function2(input_data, arg1 ....)
    do something
    etc.

if __main__=='__name__':
    process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function1, args=(data, arg1, ....)
    process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function1, args=(data, arg1, ....)
    etc.

    processes = [process1, process2, ....]
    process1.start()
    process2.start()
    .....

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

I noticed that the processes are being run one by one (not in parallel) and the .csv is reopen and scaled after each process again and again, I know that each process starts by repeating the code all the way from the top, but it takes too much time rescaling the DataFrame. I guess that the only problem is that the scaled DataFrame needs to be multiplied in memory (similar to yield I guess) and each copy is to be used by functions separately. (each function takes a copy)

I believe that this should be a simple solution, but being relatively new in multiprocessing area, I can't find that solution on my own. Pls help...

Comment: A similar discussion was here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70052925/running-a-python-script-on-16-cpus-instead-of-1-cpu/70055232#70055232 and a proposed solution is to split the data file using the `split -l`command

Comment: Splitting the data is a solution for a different problem. My problem is how to multiply the DataFrame (which sometimes can be as small as 1MB) so each function would take a copy.

Comment: I am not 100% sure I have followed your question. But why not move the creation of the `data` variable to inside the `if  __main__=='__name__':` block, which should be `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Answer (score 0):

It solved by using .copy() function whenever the original DataFrame is called and create the data varaibable inside the if__main__='**name**'

```
def function1(input_data, arg1 ....)
    do something

def function2(input_data, arg1 ....)
    do something
    etc.

if __main__=='__name__':
    data = pd.DataFrame('data.csv')
    process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function1, args=(data.copy(), arg1, ....)
    process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function1, args=(data.copy(), arg1, ....)
     etc.

     processes = [process1, process2, ....]
     process1.start()
     process2.start()
     .....

     for process in processes:
        process.join()
```